# Variable visibility inside anonymous class method

Tags: java

I have a problem with XMLTool java library. Let's consider following code:

```
private void parse() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    doc.gotoChild("Body")
       .gotoChild("ExternalListOfCodes")
       .forEachChild(new CallBack() {

            public void execute(XMLTag doc) {
                if (doc.getCurrentTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("UnitOfMeasure")){
                    //Here's the problem!                
                    list.add(
                        doc.gotoChild("UnitOfMeasureCode").getInnerText()
                    );
                }
            }
        }
}
```

There's a loop `forEachChild` and what I'd like to achieve is to add tag content to a list. Certainly, it's not possible because variable `list` is not visible there.

Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: (Note, that technically `list` is visible there, you just can't use it unless marked `final`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* visible, you just need to make it `final`:

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

More generally, an anonymous class (like your `CallBack`) can only access local variables external to the class if those variables are declared `final`.

Comment: You saved my day.. Thanks for Your fast reaction! :)

Comment: @monczek: Any decent IDE will fix this problem for you, e.g. right-click on the error in Eclipse, select "quick fix", and it'll make the variable `final`.